# Looping with for-each in schematron

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, schematron

I'm self-taught so I apologize in advance for all my mistakes.

My xml contains 50 testwithstate elements, each includes an ID attribute. I've been unable to get a for-each loop to run and I've attempted to create as simple a test as possible to find my mistakes without success. My code is below. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" queryBinding="xslt2" xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
 <ns uri="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" prefix="xlink"/>
 <ns prefix="xs" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
 
 <pattern>
  <rule context="testwithstate">
   <xsl:for-each select="/@id">
    <report test="1=1">It ran.</report>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </rule>
 </pattern>

</schema>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the `xsl:for-each` "loop" inside your Schematron schema? And which Schematron implementation do you use, which result do you want to get with the above sample and which error or result do you get instead?

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to reply.I'm only trying to learn. It's my understanding that xsl:for-each should run. To verify that it does, I expect an output of "It ran." for each instance of testwithstate, the same as when I place the <report outside the loop. As it is, I get no errors and no output. It's as if the loop doesn't execute. I don't know what implementation my employer is using and I understand that the implementation might not allow the loop to run. If you can tell me that there's nothing inherently wrong with my code then I'll conclude that it's the implementation.

Comment: I would try pure Schematron e.g. `<rule context="testwithstate/@id"><report test="true()">It ran.</report></rule>`. While using `queryBinding="xslt2"` is supposed to allow you to use some XSLT 2 declaration like `xsl:function` or `xsl:key` inside of your Schematron before any rules I think, I am not sure the general use of XSLT instructions like `xsl:for-each` is somewhere allowed or specified and has a well-defined meaning, unless you are trying to exploit the some particular XSLT based implementation or extension.

Comment: And in general with both Schematron or XSLT, once you establish a "context" like a `testwithstate` element, inside you use relative XPath expressions like `@id` to select/access the `id` attribute of the context element. Using `/@id` would try to select an `id` attribute of the document node, document nodes do not even have attributes, only element nodes have.

Comment: Thank you! All your suggestions are among those I've tried before reaching out on this forum, and the results are exactly as your describe. The loop just doesn't run as I'm implementing it. I suspect my issue is my attempt to use it in a general way, as you point out. I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: It is still not clear why you think you need to throw some XSLT into your Schematron, if you use `<rule context="testwithstate/@id"><report test="true()">It ran.</report></rule>` every `testwithstate/@id` attribute should give you a report `It ran.` on validation.

Comment: I have no particular need to use XSLT in my Schematron. I've seen many examples of for-each within XSL functions within Schematron and I was simply trying to learn whether for-each could be used in a general way. I appreciate your follow-up and your help.

Answer (score 0):

I write a lot in schematron, and when I need advanced xsl-code to run, I separate it to function, in that way you can use both in full strength. I give you an example.
This code may not make much sense to you, it is a fragment, but it shows you a way to mix schematron and xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<sch:pattern id="TPOD0470" is-a="abstractPatternWarning">
        <sch:param name="CONDITION" value="string-length(foo:foutenTPOD_0470(.)[1]) = 0"/>
</sch:pattern>
    
    <xsl:function name="foo:foutenTPOD_0470">
        <xsl:param name="context" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$context/../tekst:Titel">
            <xsl:if test="$context/@eId=@eId and not(starts-with(tekst:Kop/tekst:Nummer, concat($context/../tekst:Kop/tekst:Nummer, '.')))">
                <xsl:value-of select="@eId"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>
</sch:schema>
```